# urllib.request.urlopen is not working

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to fetch some data from a webpage using bs4, but I am having troubles opening the link. So here is the code I am using:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    my_url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa/"
    client = urlopen(my_url)
    page_html = client.read()
    client.close()
```

The curious thing is that only this particular link won't work. Others work completely fine. So what is so special about this link? And how can I open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from the `User-Agent`. Use `urllib.request.Request` to set/change the header.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa/"
client = Request(my_url, headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"})

page = urlopen(client).read()
print(page)
```